# How does WebJob QueueTrigger trigger, polling or event?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage-queues

```
public static void ProcessMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
{
    //processing message
}
```

How exactly this method will be triggered.

Is WebJob host just poling the Storage Queue.
Or Storage Queue raising new message event, that host subscribed to?

Comment: It is Polling. Azure Storage does not raise any events!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This link has your answer;

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/

> Polling algorithm
>
> The SDK implements a random exponential back-off algorithm to reduce
>   the effect of idle-queue polling on storage transaction costs. When a
>   message is found, the SDK waits two seconds and then checks for
>   another message; when no message is found it waits about four seconds
>   before trying again. After subsequent failed attempts to get a queue
>   message, the wait time continues to increase until it reaches the
>   maximum wait time, which defaults to one minute. The maximum wait time
>   is configurable.

This can help too;

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();       
config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);        
JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
```